# Replacing hot/cold water faucets for washer

Tags: faucet, replacement, clothes-washer

The faucets in the garage for my parents washer are leaking and I want to replace them.  The first issue is that I had no idea what this type of faucet is called.  I looked around the home depot website but didn't really find what i was looking for.

[image: Hot and cold faucets]

Does anyone know what type of faucets these are?  Can i just replace them with any kind of faucet?

Also, when i replace them I'm assuming i need to turn off the water at the front of house right?  Anything else I need to be careful about?

thanks!

Comment: Looks like compression fittings on 1/2" copper. If so, back the rear nuts off a few turns and twist the valves to break them loose. They'll pull off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are commonly known as "washer valves" or hot and cold "spigots". Any valve that can be threaded onto the supply pipe (3/4" or 1/2") can work. I prefer [full port ball valves](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B005JT9SBO). The  thread on the valve needs to be 3/4 inch hose thread x pipe thread.

And yes, shut the water supply to the house first. Usually at the meter or where the pipe from the street enters the house. After that open a valve outside to drain water and pressure before you remove the valves. Tape and paste the nipples before threading on the new valves.

Before connecting the hoses, turn the new valves closed (and the relief valve outside if you opened one), slowly open the main valve, back inside hold a container under each new valve and slowly open to allow air and debris to eject into the bucket. Leave open until water streams steadily. Check the filter screens in the hoses and than hand tighten. Finish with a 1/4 turn using a wrench. Check for leaks. Might want to replace hoses now also.

Answer (score 1):

A [spigot valve](http://www.homedepot.com/s/spigot?NCNI-5&gsitesearch) would be what you are looking for. You would need to remove the old valve from the pipe coming out of the wall to confirm the connection size. Washing machine hoses have the same connectors as garden hoses. Yes, turn off the whole house water since there don't appear to be shutoff valves before these valves. The main thing to worry about is to try not to damage those pipes.